# How to disable Windows 7 recycling message

Tags: windows-7, windows, recycle-bin

Some months ago, after some Windows patches (I don't know which one caused it), I started getting a recycling pop-up when deleting files. It doesn't happen every single time but it does happen most of the time. The pop-up have become increasingly annoying because it flashes up and disappears before anything can be done about it (never been able to click the "Cancel" button in time to see if it works or not).

I've been searching for a while, trying to figure out how to disable it with no luck. I did find one suggestion for the Recycle Bin to disable it prompting on file deletion, which works fine, but that doesn't prevent the Recycling pop-up.

One other odd thing that happened was that the Intel RST (Rapid Storage Technology) appears to have broke around about the same time (I can't confirm this as it happened last July but I didn't notice things right away). As a result file actions appear to be slower (no file caching perhaps). I've also been wondering if the two are possibly linked.

I'll worry about the RST later but is there a way to turn off the recycling message?

Comment: You may have a corrupt recycle bin. See here for more information: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/recycle-bin-is-corrupted-windows

Comment: We'd probably at least need to know what the pop-up says.